# stopping the music and playing it again

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I tried to make a small music file reader project , I used the code below sow i can play the music and pause it  but once I stop it and click on a button to play it from the begining the music is not played 
I used the code below and I don t know how to solve that problem :

```
 final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 try {
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +String.valueOf("/myfile.mp3"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!mp.isPlaying()){
                try{
                    mp.prepare();

                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                    mp.start();
                    btn1.setText("pause");

                }else{
                    mp.pause();
                    btn1.setText("play");

                }
            }
        });



        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                btn2.setVisibility(btn2.INVISIBLE);
                btn1.setText("play");

            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** : you can go back from the beginning  with `mp.seekTo(0);` after calling `mp.stop();` also remove the `mp.reset();` like this:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mp.stop();
            mp.seekTo(0);
            btn2.setVisibility(btn2.INVISIBLE);
            btn1.setText("play");

        }
    });
```

**Option 2** : When calling `mp.reset();` you are restoring the object into it's Idle state that's why the music cannot be played. You have to transfer the object into the Initialized state by calling `mp.setResource(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +String.valueOf("/myfile.mp3"));` and then `mp.prepare();` like this:

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            btn2.setResource(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +String.valueOf("/myfile.mp3"));
            mp.prepare();
            btn1.setText("play");

        }
    });
```

I suggest that you go for **Option 1**

I hope this helps. I haven't done any android programming but I know some Java and read the details about the MediaPlayer right [here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer)

Comment: i think that mp.reset() do that ?

Comment: @fatima I updated my answer. just tell me if there's still a problem. I'll be glad to help you find solutions. :).

Comment: yes; it works , both of them work .thank you so much

Comment: @fatima I'm glad it worked. try exploring the [Android Reference API](https://developer.android.com/reference)  you'll learn many things about the function of Classes and its methods, and much more. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the state machine of the documentation, it seems that you have to use

```
mp.stop()
mp.prepare()
mp.start()
```

This would complete the state machine.

Comment: thank you , but i dont want it to start when i click on btn1

Comment: I'm sorry I might not get your question then.

This was a proposal for button 2 since it would start from the beginning here.

What do you want to do with button 1?

Comment: btn1 is to play or pause the music and if i click on btn2 the music will be stopped if i click on btn1 after btn2 the music should restart from the beggining

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines of code in your `btn2 onClick`

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                btn2.setVisibility(btn2.INVISIBLE);
                btn1.setText("play");

                mp=new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 try {
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) +String.valueOf("/myfile.mp3"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        });
```

It will repair the media player to play again after you reset it.

This is my code implemented as you desired except I am loading music from RAW folder

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stop);
        final Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.file);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    playButton.setText("pause");
                    stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else{
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    playButton.setText("play");

                }
            }
        });



        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                stopButton.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                playButton.setText("play");
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.file);
            }
        });
    }
}
```